# execute a function in every time I choose using VB

Tags: vb.net

Is there any command in Visual basic that can execute a function every time I choose just like setInterval in Javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Sub Main()

    Dim Timer As New Timers.Timer(1000) '1000 ms
    Timer.AutoReset = True
    AddHandler Timer.Elapsed, AddressOf TimerElapsedHandler
    Timer.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub TimerElapsedHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)

    'do stuff here

End Sub
```